# Invalid register

Tags: assembly, avr

I want to make blinking led. I can't understand why registers didn't work.
This is my code:

```
; Main.asm file generated by New Project wizard
;
; Created:   Ср апр 7 2021
; Processor: ATmega328P
; Compiler:  AVRASM (Proteus)

.include "C:\Users\user\Downloads\m328Pdef.inc"

; DEFINITIONS
.list
.def temp=r16
.cseg
.org 0

      ; Reset Vector
      rjmp  Start


Start:
      ser temp
out DDRB, temp
clr temp
SBR TCCR1C, 0x00
SBR TCCR1B, 0x09
SBR TCCR1A, 0x40
Loop:
ldi temp, 1
out PortB, temp
clr temp
out PortB, temp
SBR OCR1AH, 0x0F
SBR OCR1AL, 0xFF
      rjmp  Loop
```

Registers is the inc file
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgNzx.png)
[Connection scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/285eZ.png)
WIDW?
Thank you.

Comment: Do they exist in the include file? Did you set your cpu type somewhere? Is that the correct spelling? Note that `PortB` seems to be the only one accepted.

Comment: What kind of work didn't they do?

Comment: Read the datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [AVR Instruction Set Manual](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual-DS40002198A.pdf)

Instruction **SBR** sets specified bits in a CPU (not I/O) register. **SBR** is a synonym for instruction **ORI** (Logical OR with Immediate). Instruction `SBR anything, 0x00` has no meaning, because it does nothing

You probably wanted to use **SBI** (sets one and only one bit in an I/O register: the second operand should be the bit number). But be aware - `SBI` and `CBI` work only with low 32 I/O registers. And instructions such as `IN` and `OUT` work with lowest 64 I/O registers. Other registers should be accessed using their memory-space (data space) address.

In ATmega328P (see [the datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf), 30. Register Summary at page 278) registers *TCCR1C TCCR1B TCCR1A* are accessible only using their memory addresses. Therefore you cannot use neither `SBI` nor `IN`/`OUT` on them. Instead you have to read their memory location using `LDS` and then write back using `STS`. E.g:

```
// TCCR1B = 0x09
LDI temp, 0x09
STS TCCR1B, temp

// TCCR1B |= 0x09
LDS temp, TCCR1B
ORI temp, 0x09 // or you can use SBR here - it is the same instruction
STS TCCR1B, temp
```